# Always getting +clicked_branch_link" false, really weird

Tags: ios, swift, branch, branch.io

I have integrated Branch SDK in my swift application and whenever I am installing the application through quick links, I am always getting +clicked_branch_link" : false, and that's why I can not add custom events to my application. 
1) How to check custom events before iOS application goes live?
2) Is there any way to check deep linking in test builds?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The most common issue that can lead to this behavior is a mismatch between the Branch key used in the Project and the link that you are using. If you are using debug mode, make sure to use links from the test area of the dashboard. Once you fix the issue with +clicked branch link being false, you will be able to test deeplinking and custom events.

Answer (score 1):

I am using branch.io in react native, I had the same issue on test mode, I have to declare TestMode=true in AndroidManifest.xml like code below.

In Android:

```
<meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="true" />
```

Now Branch.io part looks as:

```
    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="key_live_lm3ztzvrR4sI0dKQ76Lq6nbcsEnMV1wp"/>
    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey.test" android:value="key_test_pbXCutzyH3rH0gGP772UgdmbCsnKM3yC"/>
```